# Graceful date-parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime

I have two date parameters in a controller action that I would like to fall-back to a default value if they are nil, or parsing fails.

Unfortunately, it seems that `DateTime.strptime` throws an exception if parsing fails, which forces me to write this monstrosity:

```
starting = if params[:starting].present?
  begin
    DateTime.strptime(params[:starting], "%Y-%m-%d")
  rescue
    @meeting_range.first
  end
else
  @meeting_range.first
end
```

Feels bad man. Is there any way to parse a date with the Ruby stdlib that doesn't require a `begin...rescue` block? [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) feels like overkill for this situation.

Comment: You can get rid of the conditioning by `present?` if you are rescuing an exception.

Comment: Is it relevant to the question that you have two date parameters instead of, say, one? If not, removing unnecessary information from the question helps the reader.

Comment: @sawa the purpose of the question is to eliminate the `begin...rescue` block altogether. And your other point is just nitpicking.

Comment: The idea with `strptime` is that you already know that parsing will succeed because you've already qualified that date format as the code runs, before `strptime` sees it. `Date#parse`, `DateTime#parse` or `Time#parse` are OK for guessing the right format when you're not sure what you're getting though they stumble on dates in `%m/%d/%Y` and `%d/%m/%Y` formats.

Comment: @the Tin Man what I want is a parse function that returns a nil on failure instead of throwing an exception. `Date#parse`, `DateTime#parse` and `Time#parse` all throw `ArgumentError`. I can't think of any situation where I would want a date parameter to behave in this way in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach these days is to use  [`Dry::Types`](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-types/) for type coercions and [`Dry::Monads`](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-monads/) for representing errors.

```rb
require "dry/types"
require "dry/monads"
Dry::Types.load_extensions(:monads)
Types = Dry::Types(default: :strict)

Types::Date.try("2021-07-27T12:23:19-05:00")
# => Success(Tue, 27 Jul 2021)

Types::Date.try("foo")
# => Failure(ConstraintError: "foo" violates constraints (type?(Date, "foo"))
```

Answer (score 27):

In general, I can't agree with the other solution, using `rescue` in this way is bad practice. I think it's worth mentioning in case someone else tries to apply the concept to a different implementation.

My concern is that some other exception you might be interested in will be hidden by that `rescue`, breaking the *early error detection* rule.

The following is for `Date` not `DateTime` but you'll get the idea:

```
Date.parse(home.build_time) # where build_time does not exist or home is nil
Date.parse(calculated_time) # with any exception in calculated_time
```

Having to face the same problem I ended up monkey patching Ruby as follows:

```
# date.rb
class Date
  def self.safe_parse(value, default = nil)
    Date.parse(value.to_s)
  rescue ArgumentError
    default
  end
end
```

Any exception in value will be rose before entering the method, and only `ArgumentError` is caught (although I'm not aware of any other possible ones).

The only proper use of inline `rescue` is something similar to this:

```
f(x) rescue handle($!)
```

**Update**

These days I prefer to **not** monkey patch Ruby.  Instead, I wrap my `Date` in a `Rich` module, which I put in `lib/rich`, I then call it with:

```
Rich::Date.safe_parse(date)
```

Comment: Indeed, every time I've used an inline rescue I've regretted it. I've long since moved all my date/time parsing needs to use [timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/timeliness) instead, which behaves like I want.

Answer (score 23):

Why not simply:

```
starting = DateTime.strptime(params[:starting], '%Y-%m-%d') rescue @meeting_range.first
```

Comment: This looks like an acceptable compromise, if I must resign myself to using a `rescue`. Still feels like an antipattern, though.

Comment: It is perfectly consistent that failing to parse a value raises an exception. Similarly, if you expect a value, then a non-value is also an exceptional state. Ruby does not do this, but in many languages even the function that searches an array for a specific value raises an exception if the value is not in the array, and accessing a hash element by a wrong key does this as well (which in Ruby returns `nil`). Exceptions should not be thought of as errors, but as a state that is surprising, different from what would be normal in a given situation. If you take this view, not an antipattern.

Comment: It's the inconsistency of behavior, rather then the exception itself that I consider an antipattern. You are correct that throwing an exception is in some cases perfectly reasonable. I just wish there was an alternative here, since a failure to parse is not a surprise in this context.

Comment: The code cleans up a lot using the trailing `rescue` but can also open a new can of worms if something besides the parsing fails to the left of `rescue`. This case looks pretty benign, but it's something to be careful about. Debugging that sort of problem is annoying/frustrating/hard: Pick any two.

Comment: @TinMan: True that. You have to be sure your one line will only throw one kind of exception (or that you want the same handling for any kind of exception). But in this case the only failable part is `strptime`, and the original code also had an unrestricted `rescue`, so I figure we should be good here.

Answer (score 0):

All of the existing answers do have `rescue` somewhere. However, we can use some "ugly" methods that was available from Ruby version 1.9.3 (it was there before but there is no official description).

The method is ugly because it starts with an underscore. However, it fits the purpose.

With this, the method call in the question can be written

```
starting = if params[:starting].present?
  parsed = DateTime._strptime(params[:starting], "%Y-%m-%d") || {}
  if parsed.count==3 && Date.valid_date?(parsed[:year], parsed[:month], parsed[:mday])
    @meeting_range.first
  end
else
    @meeting_range.first
end
```

- If the date string is matching the input format, `_strptime` will return a hash with all 3 date parts. so `parsed.count==3` means all 3 parts exists.
- However a further check that three parts forms a valid date in the calendar is still necessary since `_strptime` will not tell you they are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you would to get date as object, parsed from string variable, sometimes passed string value may be nil, or empty, or invalid date string. I'd like to wrote safe metods for short:

```rb
def safe_date(string_date)
  ::Date.parse(string_date)
rescue TypeError, ::Date::Error
  ::Date.today
end
```

For example - check in irb console:

```rb
3.0.2 :001 > safe_date
 => #<Date: 2022-08-29 ((2459821j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
3.0.2 :001 > safe_date('')
 => #<Date: 2022-08-29 ((2459821j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
3.0.2 :002 > safe_date('29.12.2022')
 => #<Date: 2022-12-29 ((2459943j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
3.0.2 :003 > safe_date('29.13.2022')
 => #<Date: 2022-08-29 ((2459821j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Silently ignoring failures like this is bound to cause problems. I recommend using result types like my accepted answer.